# interaction issue with mouseover and mouseout on clip image with svg on IE11 and IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, snap.svg

This is my task :

1. I have a polygon that clip an image;
2. On mouseover, i change the plot of the polygon with an animate method;
3. On mouseout, i set back the initial plot with an animate method.

It's working fine with all browsers (IE9 too) except IE10 and IE11.
The issue is that it seems that the "clipped object" loses focus right after the mouseover and the mouseout is triggered directly for IE10 and IE11.

It's working fine if :

1. I clip any others element (text, polygon, line);
2. I remove all animate method;
3. I animate the content of the polygon (the image) and not the plot of the polygon.

I try this with two libraries : snap.svg.js and svg.js.
And the exact same issue came out.

Here a the sample code with Snap.

```
var paper = Snap(currentWidth, currentHeight).appendTo(myDocument));

 var img = paper.image($model.path+'assets/images/ui/right_layer.png');

 var circle = paper.circle(300, 300, 100).attr({
    fill: '#fff'
 });;

 var clipped = img.attr({
    clipPath: circle
 });   

 img.mouseover(function(){
      circle.animate({r: 50}, 1000);
 })

 img.mouseout(function(){
     circle.animate({r: 100}, 1000);
 })
```

Comment: May I just ask, if the same behaviour happens when you try these in the svg directly? I mean `onmouseout="circle.animate(..."`

Comment: That supposes that the svgs are already in DOM, but unfortunately, i generate them in javascript. Anyway, what is underlying your proposition ?

Comment: Had similar problem yesterday actually. So I just moved a js file above the js file generating this and appended the onmouseout to the element in the generating js.

Comment: Just thought about something else. Did you try to write mouseover and mouseout chained? img.mouseover().mouseout()...?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried both, same issues.

Comment: I am using a work around, but sill need an explanation or real solution about this issue, anyone please.
Actually i duplicate the clipPath polygon in a transparent layer that have same plot and bind event on this clone polygon that dont have a clip image and then animated the clone and the underlay clipped polygon and image at the exact same time.